# Capture WebRTC video stream in Python

Tags: python, webrtc

There is a WebRTC video stream coming from a server written in Go. I only have a URI from the stream to capture it, i.e. something like: `http://192.168.1.104:8080/stream/demo1/channel/0/webrtc?uuid=demo1&channel=0`

As I have looked into this tutorial ([webrtc-cv-tensorflow](https://webrtchacks.com/webrtc-cv-tensorflow/)), the problem is different from mine given that I have a URI from the incoming stream but they use JavaScript to "send snapshots" of video, thus asking this question. Also, in the `aiortc` repo, I found the [server example](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/blob/main/examples/server/server.py) but in my case, I want to have a Python script that captures the WebRTC video stream, not sending it.
How may I capture this stream and process the incoming video using OpenCV?

Thanks.